# save "state" app is in and relaunch app in that "state" when code is executed

Tags: java, android

To start I would like to say that I am not very experienced with Java. I have made some apps before in Android Studio so I know my way but they aren't anything special.

I want to create an app that that saves the "state" an **other** app is currently in.

With the state of the app I mean what the app is currently doing for example the app YouTube playing a video or the contacts app showing a specific contact.

It needs to be able to relaunch that state when something triggers it, for example a button on my app.

I don't need to be able to read the data I received because that isn't necessary for relaunching the app in the same state as it was when I saved it.

It also shouldn't be the state the app exited in, because that could be a different state from when I "saved" the state.

Is this achievable? If so, how?

I haven't found anything useful myself, because I have no idea where to even begin looking. I don't know apps even have a "state" and if they do how it is named because without that name I don't know what to google.

Comment: What you are describing is non-trivial. Please focus on the first problem you encounter. I propose to select one from this list: "determining all info of a known app to serialise its state for persistence", "determining all persistence info of an unknown app" (because I believe that this noticably more complex goal is what you describe), "serialising the persistence info", deserialising the persistence info", "manipulating a running other app for the reloading of persistence". None of these steps is easy and you should try to do them step by step ... and ask a question on only one at a time.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is not possible.